# CUPS - Force duplex printing

Tags: printing, duplex-printing

I'm using an Ubuntu server to provide network printing services for Windows clients (using CUPS). Printer is configured and working but if I print from a Windows client the "Default Options" in CUPS for using the duplexer are ignored. Can I somehow force CUPS to always use the duplexer regardless of what the client does?

Many thanks in advance!
Christoph

Comment: Please provide details of your Ubuntu Server, is it a Ubuntu Core Server? or Ubuntu Server, and what release of that product.

Comment: See https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSTea4CUPS#Enforcing_number-up.3D2_Printing_.281.29